# How do I deactivate widgets by name?

Tags: widgets, wp-cli

I cna get list of widgets with

```
wp widget list sidebar-1

| search          | search-2          | 1 | {"title":""}
| recent-posts    | recent-posts-2    | 2 | {"title":"","number":5}
| recent-comments | recent-comments-2 | 3 | {"title":"","number":5}
| categories      | categories-2      | 4 | {"title":"","count":0}
| meta            | meta-3            | 5 | {"title":""}
```

I can deactivate meta plugins with:

```
wp widget deactivate meta-3
```

My problem is: how can I get the id **meta-3** from widget list ?
or any other method to deactivate some widgets like meta, recent-comments etc

Comment: Like using the parameters `--fields` and `--format` for example?

Comment: yes: worked with JSON format: thanks

Comment: My pleasure, I'm adding it as an answer, to conclude this thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the `--fields` and `--format` parameter, e.g.

```
wp widget list sidebar-1 --fields=id --format=json
```

Docs: [WP-CLI Commands `wp widget list`](https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/widget/list/)